# SignalR C Client fails to receive hub message payload

Tags: c, arduino, signalr, signalr.client

I'm having difficulties receiving the hub message on a c client I'm developing.  I've been able to connect and receive an initial init message:

```
{"C":"d-3D0A11A6-w,E0|7,0|8,1","S":1,"M":[]}
```

However when the next message arrives i.e. the message received from the server hub, I run into unexpected behavior.  I receive the following:

```
&{"C":"d-3D0A11A6-:,1|BA,0|BB,1","M":[
```

But I do not receive the actual message.  I would think that the payload of the message would be something like the following:

```
{"H":"hub", "M":"broadcast", "A":["Hi!", 1]}
```

I've tried reading data 1 character at a time and also in larger chunks up to 1024.  But nothing seems to read the message from the socket.

Here is an example of the read I'm doing AFTER receiving the init message:

```
int recv_to(int fd, char *buffer, int len, int flags, int to) {

   fd_set readset;
   int result, iof = -1;
   struct timeval tv;

   // Initialize the set
   FD_ZERO(&readset);
   FD_SET(fd, &readset);

   // Initialize time out struct
   tv.tv_sec = 3;
   tv.tv_usec = to * 1000;
   // select()
   result = select(fd+1, &readset, NULL, NULL, &tv);

   // Check status
   if (result < 0)
      return -1;
   else if (result > 0 && FD_ISSET(fd, &readset)) {
      // Set non-blocking mode
      if ((iof = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0)) != -1)
         fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, iof | O_NONBLOCK);
      // receive
      result = recv(fd, buffer, len, flags);
      // set as before
      if (iof != -1)
         fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, iof);
      return result;
   }
   return -2;
}

int wait = 2;
do {
    if((n = recv_to(sockfd, buffer, 1024, 0, wait)) > -1) {
        printMsg(buffer);
        bzero(buffer, 1024);
    }
    else if(n != -1) {
        printf("received: %d\n", n);
    }
    else {
        printf("%s", "error");
        break;
    }
} while(1);
```

I have verified that I'm using an upgraded connection to use websockets. Here is the negotiate url:

```
blahblah.azurewebsites.net/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B"name":"broadcasthub"%7D%5D
```